# Enter youtube video url in input field and it should display the iframe for that video for confirmation

Tags: javascript, spring

I have a spring mvc form.Where user enter the url, clientApproval, AdminConfirmation input.Here adminConfirmation is hidden input and not visible to user.

When user enter the youtube url and clientApproval and click on submit it should show me popup window with youtube iframe for that video and confirm button.

If user click on confirm then form should submit with url, clientApproval, AdminConfirmation input.and that i will process in my controller

[image]

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">

                <form:form action="saveVideoWithConfirmation" modelAttribute="video" method="POST">
                    <br><br>
                    <hr>
  Enter youtube video url :  <form:input path="url" id="videourl" onchange="newVideo()"/>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function newVideo() {
  var select=document.getElementById('videourl').value;
  document.getElementById('myIframe').src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+select+'?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0';
  }
  </script>



                    <br>
  Do you want approval from client for this video? Yes <form:checkbox path="clientApproval" value="yes"></form:checkbox>

                    <input type="Submit" name="Submit">
                </form:form>
            </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of iFrame can be updated by using a Javascript function that gets triggered on the 'onclick' event of the button.

**Here is a working example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <p>Enter Youtube video URL: </p>
            <input type="text" id="videoUrl" placeholder="Youtube video URL" style="width: 400px;">
           <br>
           <button onclick="showVideo()">Check</button>
           <br>
           <iframe id="myFrame" width="420" height="345">fgh
           </iframe>

        <script>
            function showVideo() {
                var videoUrl = document.getElementById("videoUrl").value
                document.getElementById("myFrame").src = videoUrl
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**More information:**

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp